# Key strokes doesn't work for frames created from terminal on Mac OS

Tags: osx, frames, gui-emacs

Compiled emacs25.1 from source on MacOS. Emacs works fine when opened by click the icon.

But when open it from terminal by `emacs` or `emacsclient -a`. All the key stokes is responded in terminal instead of the Emacs frame.

Does anyone known solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've configured with --with-ns (because you said it works if you open Emacs by clicking on the app icon), then you can start Emacs from the console in a couple of different ways.  If you just want to start Emacs as an app then you can use the open command, so something like `open nextstep/Emacs.app`.  The open command has a variety of arguments which can change its behaviour.  For example, it will attempt to use an already running instance of the application if possible (you can override this with the -n argument), and by default won't wait until the application has exited (you can override this with the -w argument).  If you want to open some files as well then you'd need to use the --args argument to open to tell it that the remaining arguments should go to Emacs - for example: `open Emacs.app --args foo.txt`.

If you want to see standard output and error from the Emacs executable itself you can also run the binary directly (or in a debugger) from the terminal without using open, with something like `./Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs foo.txt`.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that running 'emacs' on macOS will probably run the version shipped with the OS which is terminal only.